# Model with a one to one field does not save after save(commit=False)

Tags: django, database, django-forms, one-to-one

I have the code blow but other fields of `patient_specification` will not be saved.
The code does not show any error and runs normally.
When i read the `patient_specification` data from db they are not changed and all except patient field are the default values.

```
# models.py

class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    national_code = models.BigIntegerField(default=1, unique=True)

class PatientSpecification(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=1)


# forms.py

class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

class PatientSpecificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = PatientSpecification
        exclude = ('patient', )


# views.py

def newPatient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_p = PatientForm(request.POST)
        form_ps = PatientSpecificationForm(request.POST)
        if all([form_p.is_valid(), form_ps.is_valid()]):
            patient = form_p.save()
            patient_specification = form_ps.save(commit=False)
            patient_specification.patient = patient
            patient_specification.save()
            return render(request, 'sfl/home.html', {})
        else:
            print('not valid')
    else:
        form_p = PatientForm()
        form_ps = PatientSpecificationForm()
    return render(request, 'sfl/new_patient.html',
                      {'form_p': form_p, 'form_ps': form_ps})
```

I also tried to replace `save(commit=false)` with `PatientSpecification()` or `patient_specification.patient = patient` with `patient_specification.patient = Patient.objects.get(national_code=patient.national_code)` but no success, `patiet_spacification` does not save normal fields.
I also tried with django shell but same problem exist.
Where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. If you still need help, show what you tried using Django shell.

Comment: Yes you are right, when i was read from database had the following mistake, used `patient_specification = PatientSpecification(patient=patient)` instead of 
`patient_specification = PatientSpecification.objects.get(patient=patient)`

Thank you for your attention